# In which circumstances is Thread.sleep() the best approach for pausing a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

`Thread.sleep()` to me seems like a really useless concept because the only way I see it working is in the following scenarios

```
 public void someFunction()
 {
      //thread does something
      Thread.sleep(50000);
      //now other threads do something
 }
```

The problem is that for me this is just asking for trouble. I mean this can either be to long in which case at best you may have a performance issue and it may be too long and other threads may wait for the result in which case the situation may become critical.

I mean there are other way like using synchronized and wait which seem much more efficient.

So my question is, are there any situations where using thread sleep is the best option?

Comment: If you are polling a non-blocking service, then Thread.sleep is useful.  Also I have used Thread.sleep to wait for a period of time before killing a ssh thread.

Comment: sleep is usueful if you want to perform a periodic task.  The concurrency library uses LockSupport.park() which is a fancier Thread .sleep().

Comment: Lots of good answers about what sleep() is for.  Here's what it's _not_ for:  It is not for synchronization.  Synchronization bugs are non-deterministic:  Sometimes they bite you, and sometimes they lie dormant.  Sometimes, adding a sleep() call in the right place can _appear_ to make a bug go away, but don't be fooled.  What really happened, is you just made the bug less active, perhaps creating a situation where, when it finally does show itself again, it will do so at an important customer's site instead of in your testing rig.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, `LockSupport.park` doesn't throw `InterruptedException`, it just gets awaken by `Thread.interrupt()`. To OP - sleep is virtually never the best choice. Personally I have written a lot of concurrent code (down to CAS,park/unpark, busy loops, etc) and network code, yet never/ever touched sleep. I consider it a very likely bug/bad code if `Thread.sleep()` is present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be impossible to write java.util.Timer without a sleep() method, or at least it would require you to abuse the wait() method, and write a lot of extra code around it to protect against spurious wakeups.

Comment: True, but if we take away the use case of writing a Timer or another higher level construction (since they already exist), there are few reasons why one would *need* to use Thread.sleep() in code.

Comment: @Kayaman If you take away the use cases where you need sleep(), you are left with the use cases that don't. The statement is tautologically true, and semantically empty.

Comment: Well, I tried to provide a more high level view, in that regular code (not writing Timers or duplicating other functionality already in the JDK) almost certainly doesn't benefit from using Thread.sleep().

Comment: @EJP This does make a lot of sense, so basically use sleep when the situation calls for actions repeated in certain time intervals. Simple, easy and did not think of that. Although id do agree with Kayaman that it would have to be a pretty exceptional case for something like this to have to be coded by a programmer and not provided by a framework(exceptions go out to the programmer of the framework obviously)

Answer (score 2):

Although many times the event-driven model is the best way to "wait" for an action to occur, there are sometimes that you need to wait intentionally for a short amount of time and then make an action. 
A common case of this is a condition of sampling/polling data (from files, from the network etc) between some periods of time. In this case, you just want to "refresh" your data in a sense between time intervals.

For example, if you have an application that makes requests to a web service via the network, you might want to have a threat to perform this task periodically, having a "sleeping" behavior most of the time, but perform the service request task after some time, repeating this behavior again and again.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a service launching 2 different threads performing 2 different things connected to each other, one of the threads fails an an exception is caught(network problem, a remote host doesn't reply), you want your service to be up and running in the shortest time possible. The best thing is to wait some time and then to re-run your failing thread. You do not know when the remote host will be up you have to test the connection. In this case the best solution is to wait for some time and then to rerun your thread and not to re-run endlessly the failing thread (CPU load).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make an observer pattern, or some other form of event driven model, programmers choice, and see when the remote host is up and then run the thread again. Basically add more logic to not waste any time.

Comment: A better approach would be to catch the exception in the thread and take whatever recovery action is required there.  One advantage of threads is that they can run autonomously and require no micro-management from other threads - you should not throw that away for negative gain.  If a network connection fails and returns an error or throws, catch it in the thread, sleep() in the thread and loop back around to reconnect, in the thread.

Answer (score 2):

Both `Thread.sleep(long)` and `Object.wait(long)` block current thread. However `wait` may return earlier (spurious wakeup), see javadoc. So for `wait` we need to implement additional logic which guarantees that specified amount of time elapsed. So if you simply want to make a pause - use `Thread.sleep`

Answer (score 1):

If the requirement spec calls for a five-second wait, maybe somewhere deep down in several functions in some process-control thread code, maybe only under some conditions, a Sleep(5000) call is a good solution for the following reasons:

- It does not require simple in-line code to be rewritten as a complex
  state-machine so as to be able to use an asynchronous timer.
- It invoves no other timer or pool thread to be run to implement the    timeout.
- It's a one-liner that does nor require wait-objects to be constructed etc.
- Sleep() is available, in almost the same form, on all multitasking OS    I have ever used.

Sleep() gets bad press because:

- It 'wastes a thread'.  In many systems, eg. when the thread is going to be there anyway and will run for the lifetime of the app, who cares?
- It is often misused for inter-thread comms polling loops, so adding    CPU waste and latency  This is indeed indefensible.
- It often cannot be interrupted so as to allow a 'clean and quick'
  shutdown of the thread.  Again, in many systems, it does not  matter if pool or app-lifetime threads get rudely stopped by a process termination, so why bother trying?

Example of reasonable usage:

```
void StartFeedstockDelivery{
  if (airbankPressure()<MIN_PRESSURE){
    startCompressor();
    sleep(10000);  // wait for pressure to build up
  openFeedValve();
};
```

Comment: This is the better answer and no single vote for. Actually `sleep` can be interrupted via `Thread.interript()` but it's still unconditional. The only semi-viable use of sleep is throttling to avoid messing up with an existing state machine, yet I'd rather have busy wait+yield and some condition check than a bland `Thread.sleep` without ability to bail out.

Answer (score 0):

You use `Thread.sleep` every time you want to slow things down. In certain scenarios you are unable to synchronize, like in case of communication with external systems over the network, database, etc.

Example scenarios:

- ***Error recovery*** - When your system depends on some external entity that reports temporary errors. You communicate with external system you have no control of and it says it has temporary issues that are not related to your request. You do `Thread.sleep` and retry. If you did not `sleep` you would get error flood. This is quite common pattern in integration middleware.
- ***Timeouts*** - You wait for something to happen but no longer than 10 seconds. You just cannot accept longer waits and want to quit.
- ***Throttling*** - Someone tells you you cannot do something more often than once a 10 seconds.

Please keep in mind that there are various ways to wait, not neccessarily by calling `Thread.sleep`.